# Using mit hand detection pkg, Point Cloud on RViz shows warning!

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, hand-interaction, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone! I am using hand detection of mit-ros-pkg.( My ubuntu version 11.04 natty and ros electric). When I "roslaunch hand_interaction hand_detector.launch" . I can get the image in the Prime Sense User TRacker Viewer. But When I "rosrun rviz rviz -d $(rospack find hand_interaction)/config/handdetection.vcg" . The status of each list is OK except three "Point Cloud2" lists of which the topic is "camera/depth/points2", "/hand0_fullcloud" and "/hand1_fullcloud". Their status is warning! And there is no image showing on RViz. But when I changed "camera/depth/points2" to ""camera/depth/points". The status of that "Point Cloud2" become OK and I can get image on RViz exactly the image on Prime Sense. Is that just luck? And how can I solved the other two warnings! I want to realize the function of hand detection! I know maybe I explain the question not clearly, Some possible reasons cause this problem will be good enough! Thank you in advance! MORE INFORMATION: The Topics in all the three "warning" drop-down lists said "NO messages received" HELP!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34745/using-mit-hand-detection-pkg,-point-cloud-on-rviz-shows-warning!!/) by [tan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2317/tan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-05-24**:
Try expanding the input sources that appear as warnings. You should be able to expand the warning drop-down to get a more detailed explanation of the error. If you post that error, we can help you better.

**Comment by [tan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2317/tan/) on 2012-05-24**:
Dimitri,Thank you very much for reply! I have checked the warning drop-down. All the three said "No messages received".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no messages because they are published on a different topic, possibly the names have changed since the package was published.

When you manually changed the name, you selected a valid topic. You can also click the topic selector and see all valid topics for the display that are published.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0